# Are there any visa-free countries for a person with Ugandan refugee passport?

Tags: visa-free-entry, refugees

I am a Congolese refugee in Uganda and I have a refugee passport (traveling document). I would like to know which countries offer a visa-free entry to Ugandan refugees with a refugee passport (traveling document).

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What research have you done on this up to now? Many countries still base your entry eligibility on your original citizenship and not on documents issued by a country where you do not hold citizenship (ie refugee documents et al). It might help you get an answer if you specified the country(ies) you are most interested in travelling to.

Comment: @Traveller "Many countries still base your entry eligibility on your original citizenship": no country I'm aware of does this (unless the refugee uses the passport of the country of citizenship, which puts the refugee's status at risk).  Which country or countries did you have in mind?

Comment: @phoog Is it not the case that in applying for a visa a refugee passport holder has to disclose their country of citizenship, even though it is the country from which they are a refugee? Timatic also requires this information. That doesn’t mean to imply they should *use* their citizenship passport

Comment: @Traveller I suppose they do have to disclose their country of citizenship.  But no visa-issuing country that I am aware of will grant a visa exemption based on that citizenship unless it is attested by a passport issued by the country of citizenship.  For example, to participate in the US visa waiver program, it is necessary to present a passport from a visa waiver country.  A French citizen who presents a refugee travel document from Germany (an unlikely example, to be sure) may not use the visa waiver program.